# Problemas al Enviar informacion por metodo Post

Tags: java, jsp, post

Realice este controlador, pero me arroja el error de la imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  Por favor requiro su ayuda. se que produce el error, segun el parse no recibe parametros pero a la hora de inspeccionar el jsp se muestra que si.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien pudiera ver completo el proyecto para que hubiera un mejor entendimiento solo haganmelo saber.

Les dejo tambien una imagen de la data:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private static final String UPLOAD_DIR="uploads";

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
Solicitud solicitud=new Solicitud(0);
String nombreParam=request.getParameter("nombre");
String emailParam=request.getParameter("email");
String telefonoParam=request.getParameter("telefono");
String direccionParam=request.getParameter("direccion");
**int rentaParam=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("renta"));** `aqui se referencia el error`
String ciudadParam=request.getParameter("ciudad");
String experienciaParam=request.getParameter("experiencia");
**int idVacanteParam=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idVacante"));**
solicitud.setFecha(new Date());
solicitud.setNombre(nombreParam);
solicitud.setEmail(emailParam);
solicitud.setTelefono(telefonoParam);
solicitud.setDireccion(direccionParam);
solicitud.setRenta(rentaParam);
solicitud.setCiudad(ciudadParam);
solicitud.setExperiencia(experienciaParam);
DbConnection conn=new DbConnection();
VacanteDao vacanteDao=new VacanteDao(conn);
Vacante vacante = vacanteDao.getById(idVacanteParam);
solicitud.setVacante(vacante);
String applicationPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");
String uploadFilePath=applicationPath+File.separator+UPLOAD_DIR;
Part archivo=request.getPart("archivo");
String archivoParam=archivo.getSubmittedFileName();
RequestDispatcher rd;
String msg="";
if(archivoParam.endsWith("pdf")||archivoParam.endsWith("doc")||archivoParam.endsWith("docx")){
String archivoFisico=Utility.randomAlphaNumeric(10)+archivoParam.replace(" ","_");
solicitud.setArchivo(archivoFisico);
SolicitudDao solicitudDao=new SolicitudDao(conn);
solicitudDao.insert(solicitud);
conn.disconnect();
msg="<b>"+solicitud.getNombre()+"</b> hemos recibido tus datos." +"<b>Revisaremos tu CV y nos comunicaremos contigo.</b>Gracias.";
request.setAttribute("message", msg);
archivo.write(uploadFilePath+File.separator+archivoFisico);
rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/mensaje_guest.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
}
else{
    msg="Solo se permiten archivos de tipo PDF,DOC y DOCX";
    request.setAttribute("message", msg);
    request.setAttribute("solicitud", solicitud);
    request.setAttribute("vacante", solicitud.getVacante());
    rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/frm_cv.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente como indicas, se produce el error cuando intenta convertir `request.getParameter("renta")` a un entero, podrías simplemente poner un try-catch

```
int rentaParam = 0;

try {
    rentaParam = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("renta"));
}catch(Exception e){
       rentaParam = -99 // ponerle un valor por defecto por ejemplo.
}
```

Piensa que te han podido enviar `1000€` cuando intente transformar la cadena a entero, dará error al parsear una letra a entero, no deberías dejar que se enviaran cosas inválidas, esas comprobaciones se hacen en el JS o Jquery o typescript, en el frontal.

Sin embargo, el error que te da es de NULL. por lo que es probable que en tu html tengas algo como input .... name = "**R**enta" e intentes recogerlo como `getParameter("renta")`

Como no has puesto el código del html, ni sabemos las comprobaciones que haces en el frontal, todo son especulaciones, además, siempre puedes poner puntos de ruptura para averiguar porque te llega el valor a null y ponerle solución tanto en el frontal como en el servidor.